# Binomial expansion with 2n power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to expand $$(z+z^{-1})^{2n}$$.

I've written the first 3 terms out but I can't figure out a way to work out the last 3 terms.
I'm trying to produce an expression for $$\cos^{2n}x$$ using the complex numbers.

Comment: $ z = x + iy = |z| (\cos \phi + i\sin \phi ) = r e^{i \phi} \ $

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the binomial formula
$$
 (z+z^{-1})^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}kz^k(z^{-1})^{2n-k}
 =\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}kz^{2(k-n)}
 =\sum_{k=-n}^n\binom{2n}{n+k}z^{2k}.
$$
Now putting $\def\i{\mathbf i}z=\exp(\i x)$ and dividing by $2^{2n}$ you get
$$
  \cos(x)^{2n}= 2^{-2n}\sum_{k=-n}^n\binom{2n}{n+k}\exp(2\i kx)
 = 2^{-2n}\sum_{k=-n}^n\binom{2n}{n+k}\cos(2kx).
$$

Comment: I dont understand the 2nd part. What is this formula?

Comment: The second equation is just applying $z^a(z^{-1})^b=z^az^{-b}=z^{a-b}$. Is that what you were asking about?